# Batch Improvement

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The below code works - but every so often I run into issues with mapping to the drives or something else goes wrong. Is there a way you can take a look at my code and help improve it?

This code allows you to copy a file from your local PC to another remote computer(s).

```dos
@echo off
if [%1]==[] goto usage
@echo mapping l: to %1\c$
net use * /delete /y
net use l: \\%1\c$ password /user:%1\administrator

if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
echo failed

 net use l: \\%1\c$ password /user:%1\administrator

) else (
goto mappingError

) > command.txt
​    
:: ---------------------------------------------

@echo copying link file to C: Drive
copy "c:\_\CopyFileToHost\logoff.cmd" l:\
​​    
:: ---------------------------------------------

@echo deleting l: mapping
net use l: /delete /y

@echo off
goto :eof

:usage
@echo Usage: %0 hostname
exit /B 1

:mappingError
@echo Error mapping remote drive, exiting
exit /B 1
```

Comment: Can you use the vertical line from the editor toolbar, instead of making your own line? They look better, and are automatically expanded full width of the post

Comment: What exactly the errors you getting?

Answer (score 0):

If the first `net use` fails, this routine *should*

1. echo failed
2. try again
3. go through to the `copying link` and deleting l mapping.

If the first `net use` succeeds, this routine *should* go to `mappingerror`, report and exit.

So - it's difficult to see how it ever worked. It *should* only ever get through to the `copy`ing if it fails the first attempt at mapping `L:` If it succeeds on the second attempt, the copy should take place. If it doesn't, a copy should be attempted but will likey fail since `L:` is not mapped.

So - hard to say since you haven't provided a report or description of what your batch is intended to do.

But, with the help of the trusty crystal ball, I'd suggest (and I have no way of testing this):

```
@echo off
if [%1]==[] goto usage
echo mapping l: to %1\c$
net use * /delete /y
net use l: \\%1\c$ password /user:%1\administrator

(
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
 echo failed
 net use l: \\%1\c$ password /user:%1\administrator
)
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
 echo Error mapping remote drive, exiting
 exit /B 1
)
) > command.txt
​    
:: ---------------------------------------------

echo copying link file to C: Drive
copy "c:\_\CopyFileToHost\logoff.cmd" l:\
​​    
:: ---------------------------------------------

echo deleting l: mapping
net use l: /delete /y

goto :eof

:usage
echo Usage: %0 hostname
exit /B 1
```

Note that once `echo off` is executed, command-echoing is turned off until the procedure ends or an `echo on` is executed. The `@` simply means `don't echo this command`.